# Windows 11 File Explorer - New Shortcut With Custom Path On Taskbar - Opens New Icon On TaskBar

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, taskbar, shortcuts, desktop

In windows 11 i created a new shortcut for File Explorer like below :

> %SYSTEMROOT%\explorer.exe /e,W:\

After creating this shortcut i dragged & dropped it to taskbar.
Now when i click on it, It opens a new icon on taskbar instead of it's own icon.
This is really annoying.
How can i fix it?

Please check the image below for double icons of windows explorer's shortcut on taskbar :

[double icons of windows explorer's shortcut on taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czQbS.png)

---

In windows 7 there was n't "File Explorer".

The name was "Windows Explorer".

In windows 11 name is "File Explorer".

So here we have two Explorers.

1. File Explorer
2. Windows Explorer After Creating a shortcut on desktop with new custom path.

After adding 1. File Explorer to taskbar we can not change it's path via properties and after opening it works normal.(One Icon)

After adding 2. Windows Explorer(We created it by ourselves and named it Windows Explorer) to taskbar & after click on it, It opens another icon and i am looking a way for prevent this action.

Comment: Windows 11 Explorer makes its own shortcut - why not just use that?

Comment: Original File Explorer is not editable for custom path such as "W:\My_Files"

Comment: I think you will have to settle for two icons (as you note, you cannot edit the original so you probably cannot replace it either).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal :
Your taskbar icon defines a shortcut, which is different from the
Explorer application itself that is being run from the shortcut.

Therefore Windows doesn't group them together.

Comment: How can i change File Explorer's path in taskbar without creating new shortcut. This is my problem. In this way there is no need to create a new shortcut and all open explorers will group with original icon.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is just not possible. The taskbar works only according to the rules as set by Microsoft.

Comment: But in old versions of windows os there was n't any problem for change that.

Comment: Windows changes from version to version.

Comment: Can we change File Explorer's path via registry?

Comment: Explorer is a big part of Windows. Your entire desktop and even the taskbar are only instances of Explorer in various modes. Even if such a registry entry existed, changing it would mean destroying Windows.